# coerce datetime using Cerberus with schema defined in config file

Tags: python, cerberus

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50158026/4655853) answer, I have defined the schema in a separate config file and using the `read_config` function to read the schema. This works fine for standard validation rules but when I define `fmt_date` I am getting `malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x123e36ad0>` error when calling the `read_config` function. How do I fix this error? I want the ability to define the schema in a config file so that I can parameterize the validation part.

```
def read_config(config_key: str):
    cParser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    cFilePath = r'config'
    cParser.read(cFilePath)
    return str(cParser.get('my-config', config_key))

doc_schema = ast.literal_eval(read_config('my_schema')) #getting error
v = Validator(doc_schema)
fmt_date = lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Schema

```
[my-config]
my_schema = {"start_date": {"required": True, "nullable": True, "type": "datetime", "coerce": fmt_date}
```